# Getting a PS3Controller to connect to a ESP32 using micropython

Tags: esp32, micropython

Has anyone been successful in connecting a PS3controller to a ESP32 using micropython. I know I can use arduino library Ps3Controller.h when programming using the arduino code.

I was looking for a module and have tried pyPS4Controller but no success. The issue seems to be the bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.L2CAP). I have not found a way around the L2CAP requirement using micropython.

Any thoughts...

Answer (score 0):

Micropython does NOT support bluetooth classic on ESP32 (which is required for PS3 controller)

Comment: The ESP32 does technically support BT Classic but there are currently no MicroPython bindings for it.

The ESP32 SDK provides two different Bluetooth stacks -- NimBLE (which only does BLE) or BlueDroid (which does both). For compatibility with other ports only provide bindings for the NimBLE stack.

So... it seems possible to do this, but it's not a small amount of work unfortunately. I was wondering if this had been done and available in a new module.

Comment: Yes, ESP32 as hardware supports required Bluetooth protocol, but it is not in Micropython by default. Maybe its possible to use external I2C Bluetooth module, like HC-05